How to Implement Unity Ads in a .NET for Android Project
I’m currently working on a .NET for Android project in Visual Studio and I’m trying to integrate Unity Ads into my application. I have the unity-ads.aar file, but I’m having trouble using it in my project.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I created an “Android Java Library Binding” project in Visual
Studio.
I added the unity-ads.aar file to my project folder.
I included the unity-ads.aar file in my .csproj file as an AndroidLibrary:

<ItemGroup>
  <AndroidLibrary Include="path_to_my_file\unity-ads.aar" />
</ItemGroup>


I added a reference to the binding library project in my main project.

However, when I try to build the project, I get many errors related to the automatic binding process. For example:
CS0249 Do not override object.Finalize. Instead, provide a destructor.
CS0738 'AdUnitActivity' does not implement interface member 'IAdUnitActivity.RequestedOrientation'. 'Activity.RequestedOrientation' cannot implement 'IAdUnitActivity.RequestedOrientation' because it does not have the matching return type of 'int'.
CS0507 'InitializationStatusBridge.ClassName': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'GenericBridge.ClassName'

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement Unity Ads in a .NET for Android project? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
